# I have two console apps one is client other server and they communicate using WCF. How to run those apps like different users in VS

Tags: c#, wcf, certificate

Secyrity service represents server.I want to run Client for example like Mark and Secyrity service as John(https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8yRA.png)

I was following pdf file from my profesor and it is reffering me to Computer Managment into local users and groups section but i dont know what is there to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run code on the service in context of the user of the client you need to use impersonation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-impersonate-a-client-on-a-service

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I found it by myself, the thing is you must go to debug folder of the client or service, hold shift, and then press run it as a different user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know a more complete wcf service setup process, you can refer to the steps in [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial), from creating wcf services, configuration files, wcf clients, testing, step by step.